# How to import files from different locations on server using python?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to import multiple files from different folders (in different directories) on my shared drive. But when I use the change directory function, I can only select one path.

Is there any way I can import files from multiple folders? Idea is to import 2-3 different files (.txt or /pdf) and merge them into one output file.

I have been using the following code so far:

```
pip install PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os
chdir = os.chdir("C:/Users/47124")
merger = PdfFileMerger()
input1 = open("File1", "rb") #what is rb and wb?
input2 = open("File2", "rb")
merger.append(fileobj = input1)
merger.append(fileobj = input2)
output = open("document-output.pdf","wb")
merger.write(output)
output.close()
```

Note: File1 and File2 are in different locations; They cannot be placed in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change directories within your python code, just define the filenames as absolute paths (complete path). So instead of e.g. `File1.pdf` or `MyFolder/File1.pdf` which are relative, change it to absolute e.g. `/home/ptklearning/Documents/MyFolder/File1.pdf` or `C:\Users\ptklearning\Documents\MyFolder\File1.pdf` or wherever it is.

### Sample code:

```
merger = bytes()

filenames = [
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/GitHub/myproject/src/notes/file1.py',
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/Program/file2.txt',
    # Add more files as you wish. Note that they would be appended as raw bytes.
]

filename_output = "document-output.txt"

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_input:
        file_content = file_input.read()
        merger += file_content

with open(filename_output, 'wb') as file_output:
    file_output.write(merger)
```

Contents of document-output.txt:

```
# This is file1.py
# A dummy line within file1.py
While this is file2.txt!



Nothing more from this 2nd file...

file2 wants to say goodbye now!
```

### Sample code (using PDF files):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()

filenames = [
    '/home/nponcian/Documents/Program/StackOverflow_how_to_python.pdf',
    '/media/sf_VirtualBoxFiles/python_cheat_sheet.pdf',
    # Add more files as you wish. Note that they would be appended as PDF files.
]

filename_output = "document-output.pdf"

for filename in filenames:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(filename, strict=False))

with open(filename_output, 'wb') as file_output:
    merger.write(file_output)
```

Contents of document-output.pdf:

```
<Combined PDF of the input files>
```

### Note:

- `rb` signifies Read-Binary
- `wb` signifies Write-Binary (if you want
  to always overwrite the output file)
- `ab` signifies Append-Binary (if
  you want to just append new merges to the output file)

You need the explicit `b` (binary) if you are processing files that are not the usual text files such as docx, pdf, mp3, etc. Try opening them with a text editor and you would know what I mean :) Such files would be read as a `python-bytes` object and not as `python-str` objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I observed just now the files are located on a server. So it is a ".com" extension rather than the usual C:\\User\\ path.

Comment: Can we give/convert the server path to this python code and retrieve the files?

Comment: This answer is only applicable for files within the same computer/server, thus not applicable if the file is in an external computer/server. If the files are in an external computer, then you need to download those files first, or at least get the contents (text or base64 data) of those files. The way you would do this depends on the server/storage you are using. If that server/storage exposes an API that you can call (which as you said has .com extension) for you to get those files, you can use python-requests to send HTTP requests e.g. <file1 = requests.get(url_of_file1)> to get those files.